# How do I go to a third activity?

Tags: java, android

I read on here how to go from the MainActivity to a second activity, unfortunately I still don't fully understand what's going on, because if I use the same code to go from the second activity to a third it won't work, so, yeah copying code without understanding is always a problem. So, in general what's the easiest most basic way to just go from activity to activity to activity. In other words for now I want let's say 5 activities I can jump back and forth through by pressing a button.

```
package com.example.human.hurdlesb;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity2Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
    Button btnScreen3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScreen3);
    btnScreen3.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

it complains that "view cannot be applied to...('this' seems to be the problem although the same code works in the MainActivity class

```
@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate ...
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and overriding the superclass seems to be another problem...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Log.i("click", "you clicked");
    Intent i = new 

 Intent(MainActivity2Activity.this,MainActivity3Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

}
```

Comment: did you declare in manifest your 3rd activity?

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't work"? How does it fail? From you question it seems like compilation errors are the problem. Is this the case or does the app run but the 3rd Activity never starts?

Comment: doesn't compile , says at the override onClick version that it doesn't override method from superclass . and the "this" in setOnClicklistener :cannot be applied to ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have stated will not compile because `MainActivity2Activity` needs to implement the `View.OnClickListener` interface. The `onClick()` method that you override comes from this interface and without implementing it, you cannot override the method. Hence your compilation failure.